# Export highcharts animation as video

Tags: animation, highcharts, html5-video, video-capture

We're evaluating highcharts for an application. 
http://www.highcharts.com

Does anyone know if there is a possibility to export a highchart animation into a video file? 
Or to export it to multiple images from which we can create an animation video?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible, you can export only for static file.